# Ruby version mismatch Atom rubocop linter

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

Using RVM and I have a .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset in my directory. I'm trying to use the rubocop linter while editing with Atom. It constantly gives me a Ruby version mismatch error that I cannot track down. You'll notice in the stack trace that when it runs the Rubocop command, somehow it thinks the Ruby version is the System Ruby version instead of the version that I'm currently using with RVM. The stack trace is below:

```
Error: /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:417:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.7 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:91:in `setup'
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:94:in `setup'
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:124:in `check'
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:131:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.4/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `call'
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Users/jaredrader/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@bloc/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
    at /Users/jaredrader/.atom/packages/linter-rubocop/index.coffee:30:15
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. It was because I had set the rubocop path directly in my atom `config.cson` file for linter-rubocop. The error will go away if you point to the path for the version of ruby you want to use.